# Cant see call log on Sony Xperia M4 Aqua

Tags: call-history

This is all I get when I follow the instructions for viewing your call log.

When I get a missed call, the notification shows at the top and when I click it then I get this screen. I can't find anywhere else on the phone to view my call log.

Please help!!!

[image: no call log]
<sup>Click on the image to enlarge</sup>

Comment: When you tap the "overflow menu" (the "three stapled dots" at the upper-right corner), do you get the option to switch to the call log? If so, does it show up, or does it stay empty as well?

Answer (score -1):

I finnaly found the solution. 
Turn off guest mode option in your mobile. DONe

Answer (score -2):

One of the ways is to factory reset your phone,if that problem appears again you should do a hard reset. Check some tutorials if u dont know how to hard reset.

Answer (score -2):

Just restart your mobile. I also had same problem but it's resolved after restarting my mobile